# Creating a custom Wall Post with Facebook API on Android

Tags: android, api, facebook

I'm new to Facebook API on Android, and basically, what I'm trying to do is creating custom wall post for an application I'm developing.
Like when you listen a Shazam a song and you can share the result with your friends.
I believe I've got to create a custom attachment. Here's my code for setting the attachment:

```
mPostButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle myParams = new Bundle();
        String attachment="{\"name\":\"Gran Turismo 5\"," +
           "\"href\":\"http://www.unknown.com/?lang=fr\"," +
           "\"caption\":\"Sony Computer Entertainment\",\"description\":" +
           "\"Une vidéo proposée par Cedemo.\",\"media\":" +
           "[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":" +
           "\"http://www.unknown.com/prepicture//thumb_title/15/15061_1.jpg\"," +
           "\"href\":\"http://www.unknown.com/?lang=fr\"}],\"properties\":" +
           "{\"Autre lien\":{\"text\":\"Cedemo\",\"href\":\"http://www.unknown.com\"}}}";
        myParams.putString("attachment", URLEncoder.encode(attachment);
        mFacebook.dialog(Option.this, "stream.publish",myParams,
                new SampleDialogListener());
```

And then, later on:

```
public class SampleDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
            mAsyncRunner.request(postId,values, new WallPostRequestListener());
        } else {
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "No wall post made");
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't wrote the attachment String, It's just a test taken from another question made in this forum. Anyway, when I call myAsync.request, my app shows an error message, how am I supposed to pass the attachment to my dialog?
Hope I've been clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need to set custom parameters?  It sounds like you can just want to post a Facebook message directly to the wall: you can do this by simply handing in the message parameter as a string -- you only need all that JSON if you want to attach an image etc.  And note on facebook's page it says using this api call won't post a status update that others can see on their feed, it will just appear on their [own wall](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish).  If you just want to post a message with a link you should just be able to use your mAsyncRunner (once you have your valid Facebook session) using this:

```
String message = "Post this to my wall";
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();        
parameters.putString("message", message);   
mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener());
```

Also may help if you posted the error/response code you're getting from Facebook.

Comment: Your answer solved me a lot of problems. Had a problem because I didn't specify POST in mAsyncRunner.request. Thanks a lot.