# How to launch an installed facebook app along with an status image from my app in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

In my android app there is an image, on clicking that image the facebook app should open up, with that image attached to the status field(empty) to post it on the user's wall.

I was able to open up only the facebook app from my app using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

waiting for the response..

Comment: What you exactly want ... do you want to post the image (share the image ) on FB when clicking on that image ..... or something else ??

Comment: thanks for the reply , yes exactly ... i want to share the image on my wall on click of that image ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/

it may helps you.

Comment: Is there any way that i can open an intent of the facebook app installed with sharing that photo.. ?

Comment: This is not possible but you can try with attachment using Bundle.

Comment: you have to try with Custom Wall post like this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206296/creating-a-custom-wall-post-with-facebook-api-on-android