# How to post image with link on facebook from android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post image (from gallery) and a link to android market on my facebook wall from my android app, but i have tried every possible post on this topic but not working for me.
can any one help me to post on facebook.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to pick the image from gallery dynamically or any static  image from gallery as in case of dynamically selecting the image you have to give some option to pick the image from gallery , so what you exactly want... .... ???

Comment: You can try this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206296/creating-a-custom-wall-post-with-facebook-api-on-android. The Way of attachment in this post is working in my app so you can try it with little modification.

Comment: no the image is static in my case

Comment: @Ajay can i apply this code to attach file from my sd card also

Answer (score 0):

After integrate fb sdk in  your project, you write the code when publishing(in this code-->"HERE JUST WRITE YOUR IMAGE URL".here you need to write image url).

```
parameters.putString("attachment", "{\"caption\":\""+"NAME"+"\","
    +"\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\","
    +"\"name\":\""+"bhargav"+"\",\"description\":\""+"hey....."+"\","
    +"\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\""+"HERE JUST WRITE YOUR IMAGE URL"+"\",\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\"}]"
    +"}");

mFacebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish",parameters,
    new SampleDialogListener());
```

It is working code in my application.

Comment: but my image is in gallery can i pass pathof that image in that place